# How do I create a local server on my PC to build an API on that will handle http requests from Flutter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, express, web-development-server

I've never created my own API so please bear with me. In the long run, my API will run on a dedicated, more robust server, but for now I just want to create something on my local PC that will let me start writing backend functions for it. The API should:

- Validate incoming requests by device ID, user login, and network
- Take parameters from the request and send them to SQL Server (which will then run a stored proc with those parms), then when SQL Server is done processing it should send the results back to the client device

How do I get started? I know I want to use Node.js, but what is Express.js? I'm out of the loop on which one to use here.

Comment: Look at shelf, shelf_router, shelf_static. With these you can write a server in Dart - and keep to one language.

Comment: @RichardHeap that's an interesting idea - I never even thought about the possibility of writing server side code in Dart

Comment: We use PostgreSQL as our back end database and there's good Dart support. Not sure about SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Express is a framework to create an HTTP/HTTPS server.

In your case, I'd recommend you go with a template that already has part of the setup done for you. One known template manager that is good to user is yeoman. With yeoman there are different templates you can choose from, [here's an example of one that is for express APIs](https://github.com/cdimascio/generator-express-no-stress) You can start with these commands:

`npm install -g yo generator-express-no-stress

`yo express-no-stress myapp`

`cd myapp`

`npm run dev`

this wll already start the server for you and you'll have an initial setup to start your work.

Comment: Would this also be what I would use on a production environment where we might have to do more complex custom work? Whatever I use there will need to stable and give me as many options as I might need.